# The command "pip show <module>" gives a path to the installed module that does not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, anaconda

I am trying to install the [python-Levenshtein module](https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/) on a virtual machine that I use at work. Due to security reasons, I am unable to use pip over the network and am using a downloaded wheel of the module.

Here are the steps involved:

1. I install the module from the wheel (chosen appropriately for my Python version and system architecture) using the command `pip install <path/to/wheel>`. Pip tells me the operation is a success.
2. I go to the python console, try importing and I get an error (This error isn't the topic of this question):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\App-V\A732B7F4-79EC-40EE-A281-DAC20EA5E7BF\1D5AEA95-AB24-433E-A9C0-19FF6C84E7FA\Root\lib\site-packages\Levenshtein\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Levenshtein import _levenshtein
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

3. Since a DLL seems to be missing, I try and see what's present in the path to the module. I run `pip show python-Levenshtein` and obtain a path. This is the same path as shown in the error message above.
4. **This path does not exist**. The path is something like `C:\ProgramData\App-V\{string}\{string}\Root\Lib\site-packages\Levenshtein\`. The path till sub-directory `site-packages` exists. Within site-packages, I can find other modules (like numpy etc). The folder `Levenshtein` does not exist, however (even among hidden folders).

I am a bit lost here. Where does python read that module from if the folder does not really exist where pip says it exists? Even the error traceback shows the same path (which does not exist).

Comment: Why is this tagged with `anaconda` ?

Comment: @AMC sorry I didn't make it explicit. I am using the anaconda environment. I thought it would be relevant.

Comment: You’re using a Conda environment on that machine, and that’s where you’re trying to install the module?

Comment: @AMC yes. conda prompt > pip install <path/to/wheel>